# PHP: How to make variable visible in create_function()?

Tags: php, preg-replace, global-variables, preg-replace-callback, create-function

This code:

```
$t = 100;
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/",
                            create_function(
                                  '$matches',
                                  'return $matches[1] + $t;'
                            ), $func);
```

How to make $t visible from create_function() in preg_replace() function?

Comment: You should use closures instead http://php.net/functions.anonymous `function($matchtes)use($t){/*..*/}`

Comment: @hakre `"1" + 100` ;) But I see, what you mean: The regular expression matches something starting with `Name`, thus the function will always return `100` (`=$t`). Probably not wanted.

Comment: The solution depends on what version of PHP you are using. Ideally, the solution is to use a closure passing in the $t variable to the `use` construct. This requires at least PHP 5.3. BTW, if the value of $t doesn't every change, you might consider using a constant which will be available in any context.

Answer (score 3):

An [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) would work, while making use of the `use` syntax:

```
$t = 100;
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/",
    function($matches) use($t) // $t will now be visible inside of the function
    {
        return $matches[1] + $t;
    }, $func);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the variable accessible, but in your case you can just use the value:

```
$t = 100;
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/",
                            create_function(
                                  '$matches',
                                  'return $matches[1] + ' . $t .';'
                            ), $func);
```

However, it is *highly* recommended you use the `function($matches) use ($t) {}` syntax here (http://php.net/functions.anonymous).

And there is eval modifier for `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/e", '$1+'.$t, $func);
```

But I have the feeling that your function is using the wrong operator here anyway - or the wrong pattern / subpattern.

Answer (score 0):

Same way you make *any* function see a global variable.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/",
                            create_function(
                                  '$matches',
                                  'global $t; return $matches[1] + $t;'
                            ), $func);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$GLOBALS` but its not highly recomended ...

```
$str = preg_replace_callback ( "/(Name[A-Z]+[0-9]*)/", create_function ( '$matches', 'return $matches[1] + $GLOBALS["t"];' ), $func );
```

Better Solution

http://php.net/functions.anonymous anonymous function  .. if you don't like to use that you can also do  `array_walk` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php ) after you have gotten the result in an array format then pass `$t` as a proper function argument

Answer (score 0):

in anonymous just use the keyword **use**  or **global**
in create_function use **global**

> function() use($var1,$var2...etc){code here}

or

> create_func($args,'global $var1,$var2;code here;');

Comment: Beware! `global` only imports variables from the global scope, not from the scope where the function is defined, like `use` does.