# How to submit an outside variable to Gravity Forms through WP filter

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This type of work is new to me, so please be patient if the answer is something easy.

I'm using Wordpress and Gravity Forms on my site, and I want to pre-populate the form with data from an object (the object comes from an API, so I can't just use wordpress current_user object).

How can I use an outside variable inside a wordpress filter?

For Example:

```
$fname = $object->first_name;
add_filter('gform_field_value_firstname', *Populate the field with $fname*);
```

The below is the normal usage of the function, from Gravity Forms Docs (http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_value_$parameter_name)

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_firstname', "dothis");
```

Where "dothis" points to a function.

The below also works (based on this excellent article: http://www.doitwithwp.com/pre-populate-fields-using-gravity-forms/):

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_firstname', create_function("", 'return "John";' ));
```

However, I can't figure out how to get it to accept an outside variable also.  For example, I'd like to do:

```
$fname = $object->first_name;
add_filter('gform_field_value_firstname', create_function("", 'return $fname;' ));
```

But php tells me that fname is an undefined variable.

I've reviewed this thread [PHP: How to make variable visible in create_function()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131335/php-how-to-make-variable-visible-in-create-function) , but I could not get the Closure solutions to work. I have PHP Version 5.2.17.

Would you please post an example of how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$fname` a global variable and you can reference it in your `create_function` as a global.

```
global $fname = $object->first_name;
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_firstname', create_function( '', 'global $fname; return $fname;' ) );
```

However if you have multiple values to return, it's better to make $object global:

```
global $object;
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_firstname', create_function( '', 'global $object; return 
$object->first_name;' ));
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_lastname', create_function( '', 'global $object; return $object->last_name;' ));
```

And so on...