# PHP regex - find and replace link title if the link contains specific string

Tags: php, regex, replace, html-parsing

I am trying to do this regex match and replace, but am not able to do it.

Example

```
<a href="../files/...">One</a>
<a href"../files/...">Two</a>
<a href="three">Three</a>
<a href="four">Four</a>
```

I want to find each set of the a tags and replace with something like this

Find each link that contains "/file" string in href

```
<a href="../files/...">One</a>
```

and Replace its name to

```
<a href="../files/...">One (FileType Filesize)</a>
```

same way the rest of the a tags.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`(<a href(?=[^>]*\/file)[^<]*)(<\/a>)` will find the links you're interested in. Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/tG4fT1/1 . If your desired substitute is static, you can do it with regex and `preg_replace` alone.

```
$re = "/(<a href(?=[^>]*\\/file)[^<]*)(<\\/a>)/"; 
$subst = "$1 (Filetype Filesize)$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Now, this is assuming you actually want the string `(Filetype Filesize)` added, not the actual values of `Filetype` and `Filesize`, and it's what your question looks to tackle. If it's the values, it gets more complicated and, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131370/4635642), you might have to use anonymous functions for that, while also specifying the correct match for each value.